# display wrong and no response when pass a parameter to a js routine

Tags: javascript, php

Purpose is that I want to pass a array value to a js routine in my php file.

```
$friend = get_friend();
$friendList = json_encode($friend);
```

I use below code to call js routine:

```
<td><input id="addNew" type="button"  value="new" style="width:150px;" onclick="Exam.newItem('<?php echo $friendList;?>');"></td>
```

Below is what I get when I use 'inspect element' in firefox, the button no response.

```
<input id="addNew" value="new" style="width:150px;" onclick="Exam.newItem('{" pass":0,"0":{"id":"1","name":"\u6211\u7684\u670b\u53cb1"},"1":{"id":"2","name":"\u6211\u7684\u670b\u53cb2"},"total":2}');"="" type="button">
```

not sue how "="" comes out before type

Thanks.

Comment: what is your requirement and how is the ''=" blocking your issue? If u can elaborate the requirement, we can see if there are other ways of achieving the same,

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the specifics but I've had a similar problem when JSON encoding before.
Try rearranging the string construction:

```
$friend = get_friend();
$friendList = json_encode($friend);
$myawesomeevent = 'Exam.newItem(\'' + $friendList + '\');';
```

and editing your markup:

```
<td><input id="addNew" type="button"  value="new" style="width:150px;" onclick="<?php echo $myawesomeevent;?>"></td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: not work. it displays as <input id="addNew" value="new" onclick="0" type="button">

Comment: Is your get_friend() function returning well formed JSON?